# SDL2: Multiple renderers for multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, sdl-2

I am using SDL2's `SDL_Renderer` to:

1. draw various shapes into textures
2. showing those textures in the window

As the first step can be time-consuming due to the amount of shapes, I am considering putting it into a separate thread. A texture that is not finished would simply not show (I can ensure that in my code), but the application wouldn't have to wait for the step 1 to complete.

But I am not sure how to handle the renderer object: currently I am using a single global one for both steps 1 and 2. If I just do 1 and 2 in two threads with the same renderer object, it is going to fail miserabely, right? But I am not sure if I can create two separate renderer objects?

The answer of the question: [SDL2 Multiple renderers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792146/sdl2-multiple-renderers) suggests that renderers are tied to specific windows and I am using just one.

Comment: You most likely don't want to render to the same surface from multiple, but more likely you want to create the textures on secondary threads, and include a flag to tell the render thread whether they're ready.

Comment: Yes. But I need multiple `SDL_Renderer` objects - something I am not sure if it is allowed.

Comment: It probably can be done but likely to be poorly tested area, so expect problems. Also it may highly depend on chosen rendering backend. However, it is quite unlikely it will help you solve your initial problem. If rendering backend is hardware-accelerated (opengl/d3d), then extra thread wins nothing as operations performed by the same GPU and driver is threaded anyway. And even if you'll get it working, you cannot use the same texture in two renderers (because it is tied to renderer at creation time), so you'll need to download texture from one renderer and then download it again to another.